# How to retrieve events older than 3 years old from EKEventStore

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit, ekeventstore

I just ran the following code (on my iPhone):

```
  let predicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -60*60*24*365*4), end: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60*60*24*30), calendars: [calendar])
```

The results show that this request only goes back 3 years:

> earliest start date found: 2015-04-11 12:00:00 +0000

Is there a way to retrieve calendar events older than three years? I'd like to retrieve my old class notes.  When I use the calendar on the mac, it lists counts for each calendar, yet I'm unable to retrieve the older objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

** **Updated answer** **

I dug into this a bit more and found the [following from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekeventstore/1507479-predicateforevents) which explains why the OP Is having this problem:

> For performance reasons, this method matches only those events within
>   a four year time span. If the date range between startDate and endDate
>   is greater than four years, it is shortened to the first four years.

With that said, you can just create four year increments with the following code as an example:

```
if let fourYearsAgo = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -4, to: Date()) {
    let predicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: fourYearsAgo,
                                                  end: Date(),
                                                  calendars: [calendar])
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have also been getting older events when I narrow the predicate's event timespan.  I guess I'll just futz with different approaches until I'm satisfied I have most/all the data I expect.

Comment: @Mozahler Updated with information from Apple that explains why this is happening.

Comment: But I'm getting back only 3 - not the requested 4.  Granted my query spans 4 yrs and a month. In any event, thank you for your efforts. I'm glad you took the time to get back to me.

Comment: The daily horror with Apple -- there were a bunch of choices made that led to this even being a performance issue. Yet another limitation where one wishes Apple had left this choice to the developer, perhaps along with a warning of potential performance problems. Thanks for pointing it out.